# CS0143: for Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect

My error is CS0143, The type 'Microsoft.Kinect.KinectSensor' has no constructors defined

I checked other questions similar to this but did not understand the answers they gave.  Essentially the class I am writing is just an initializer for the kinectSenor.

Any help would be great...thank you!

```
public class KinectInitialize 
{

    KinectSensor _kinectSensor = new KinectSensor();

    #region Constructors
    public KinectInitialize()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    void SetAllFramesReady(KinectSensor Kinect)
    {
        Kinect.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(Kinect_AllFramesReady);
    }

    internal void RemoveOldSensor(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _kinectSensor = (KinectSensor)e.OldValue;
        StopKinect(_kinectSensor);
    }

    public KinectSensor CreateNewSensor(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _kinectSensor = (KinectSensor)e.NewValue;

        return _kinectSensor;
    }

    internal void StopKinect(KinectSensor sensor)
    {
        if (sensor != null)
        {
            sensor.Stop();
            sensor.AudioSource.Stop();
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: DO you have a parameterless constructor for Kinect Sensor?

Comment: The code included here doesn't really do anything with the `_kinectSensor` field besides assign to it. Is the field even necessary?

Comment: M.Babcock - That is a good question.  I am trying to figure out the best way to work with it.  I think I am just trying to set up one class where the sensor exists then I can manipulate it from there.  If that makes sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public constructor on the `Kinect` class - there is however a public static collection `KinectSensors` from which you can just grab the first one in status `Connected`:

```
KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors
                                  .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Status == KinectStatus.Connected);
```

I assume this is done for convenience because you can have more than one Kinect attached to your machine.